# NSubstitute for the EF's Core DbContext - how to use it?

Tags: nsubstitute, ef-core-3.1

I'm trying to create the unit test for a class which uses my `EF Core DbContext`:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<SomeTable> SomeTables { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

the class which is consuming that context is simple:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(MyContext db)
    {
    }
}
```

so, when I try to create

```
var fakeContext = Substitute.For<MyContext>();
```

which ends with the error:

```
Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can not instantiate proxy of class: MyContext.
Could not find a parameterless constructor.
```

which is being raised by `base(options)` constructor. So, the net approach was to extend the code:

```
var dbContextOptions = Substitute.For<DbContextOptions<MyContext>>();

dbContextOptions.ContextType.Returns(typeof(MyContext));

var dbContextOptionsExtension = Substitute.For<IEnumerable<IDbContextOptionsExtension>>();
dbContextOptions.Extensions.Returns(dbContextOptionsExtension);

var myFakeContext = Substitute.For<MyContext>(dbContextOptions);
```

but it generates more and errors. So, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 6):

You haven't elaborated on the additional errors so I can't provide a specific answer, however trying to mock a DbContext properly is difficult. IMO there are two options.

1) Use the [Microsoft in-memory provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory).

2) If you want to use a mocked DbContext using NSubstitute, use a pre-existing library that does the mocking for you. There are a few around such as [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing.NSubstitute](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing) (disclaimer - I am the author).

The in-memory provider is not a complete implementation, it can't do relational operations and there are a swag of LINQ operations it doesn't support, so depending on your use cases the latter may be a better solution.

If you have a specific error/use case in mind pop it up and I may be able to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've used the `InMemory` provider:

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AgreementContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase("fakeDb")
                .Options;

var agreementContext = Substitute.For<MyContext>(options);
```

Comment: Consider using a guid or something unique per test for the database name https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory#writing-tests